# Is there an easier way to handle many pieces of data changing in an ios app?

Tags: ios, key-value-observing, large-data

I have an app I am working on, and it has a number of pieces of data that are interdependent.  Basically, I have a set of number fields that are used to calculate other number fields, which are then used to calculate other fields.  I am trying to determine the best way to handle the potentially large number of changes.

One solution I thought of is that I could override the setters of the values that can be modified by the user to do the calculations and then update the other values in data object appropriately.  The largest downside to this is the sheer amount of (somewhat boilerplate) code that needs to be written.

Another solution I thought of is using Key-Value Observing to handle the data changes, and to then update the dependent values from those changes.  Note that none of the dependent values will ever update except when an independent value updates.  While I think this will be a bit more elegant, I am concerned about potential performance problems, or problems that I am possibly not considering.

Is there a third way that I am missing?  Are there any best practices for this type of work?  I know that I am likely going to have to write a bunch of boilerplate code of some sort - I would like the code to be the easiest to maintain, and the smallest amount of code possible.

Comment: In case people are wondering, I have a lot of experience in a similar, but still significantly different environment - Java.  Being still fairly new to the iOS ecosystem, I am trying to feel my way around and find the best/recommended ways of doing things to make sure that my software is as maintainable and correct as possible.

Comment: In case someone sees this question in the future - I went ahead and did Key-Value observing, given that it was the easiest for me to work through, and I didn't want to work with the full notification system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVO shouldn't have any performance issues unless you have very many fields or very frequent updates, but its API isn't the greatest. One downside is that it funnels all notifications through a single method. This may or may not be an issue depending on your number and types of fields.

[Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) might also be a good option. Each field could have a notification name that it would post changes from, and other fields could observe without an explicit pointer to the source field.

There is also [delegation with protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/02_DesignPatterns.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH10-SW5) which, while simpler and more performant, can be rather boilerplate-heavy depending on how you do it.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid delegation with protocols, simply because of the boilerplate code surrounding it.  I will look into the notifications however - thanks for the tip!